# Знак :: в c++

Tags: c++

Переписываю коды с плюсов на java. Никак не могу понять, что значит этот знак "::", который встречается повсюду?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это означает расширение области видимости, «выход» из namespace.

Пример:

```
void f() { cout << "outer f" << endl; }

namespace ns
{
    void f() { cout << "inner f" << endl; }
    void g()
    {
        f(); // выводит "inner f"
        // а как вызвать внешнюю f?
        // а вот как:
        ::f(); // выводит "outer f"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Помимо ответа выше есть еще использование, например для вызова статических методов класса.

```
class MyClass{
public:
    static int func();
    static int value;
};

int MyClass::func(){ // Здесь мы находимся за областью класса MyClass.
    //поэтому, с помощью оператора разрешения контекста '::'
    //указываем какой конкретно метод реализуем.
    value = 15;
}

int main(){
    MyClass::func(); // Обращение к статическому методу        
    MyClass::value; // Обращение к статическому полю
    return 0;
}
```